# Calculating probability increase of adding dice to pool

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, dice

I am trying to work out the chance of hitting a target number using the highest result of 1, 2, or 3 20-sided dice, and I am now trying to figure out how this result is changed by the addition of various other dice. An extra complexity to this formula is that a result of 1 on the 20-sided dice cannot be altered and always fails. I have managed to get a formula for adding a single die:

$$p=\frac{1}{20^xn}((n(y-1)^x-(n-y+2))-
\begin{cases}
(\frac{(y-2)(y-1)}{2})^2, \text{ if } x=3\\
\frac{(y-2)(y-1)(2(y-2)+1)}{6}, \text{ if } x=2\\
\frac{(y-2)(y-1)}{2}, \text{ if } x=1\\
\end{cases}\Biggr)$$

where x is the amount of 20-sided dice, n is the faces of the additional die, and y is the target value.

The result of the above formula works out added chance of reaching the target, on top of the highest result of the 20-sided dice. So if we are trying to reach 4, the chance of 2 20-sided dice being at least 4 would be $b=1-(1-\frac{21-4}{20})^2=0.9775$, and the chance added by adding a 4-sided die using the above formula would be $p=0.018125$, for a total of $t=b+p=0.995625$. Keeping in mind that a 1 on the 20-sided die result cannot be altered by adding more dice and always fails.

But after doing that my brain is fried. Does anyone know how to expand this formula to incorporate n dice with variable sides, for example, a 4-sided die and a 6-sided die? From my calculations, the below should be the desired $p$ results of the formula for each value of $y$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
y & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ \hline
p & 0.0075 & 0.0125 & 0.037291\dot{6} & 0.0726041\dot{6} & 0.1153125 \\ \hline
y & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12+ \\ \hline
p & 0.1611458\dot{3} & 0.2080208\dot{3} & 0.2538541\dot{6} & 0.2986458\dot{3} & 0.342708\dot{3} \\ \hline
\end{array}

If a formula for the total probability is easier than increased probability, then that would also be acceptable.

As a bonus, much simpler question, is there an equation for finding the chance to roll an exact value on multiple dice? Using the above example, a 4-sided die and a 6-sided die? Everywhere I look online is 2 dice with the same number of sides and uses a table of results.

Answer (score 1):

So, we can make this a little less complex by reframing the question: What we're asking is "given a target number, what is the probability of more than 0 dice equalling or exceeding that target?". Ultimately, it doesn't really matter which die has the highest number in this scenario, we really just care if any of the dice reached the target.

This lets us redefine the problem as a binomial distribution, and allows us to use the binomial equation instead. Let us define $t$ as our target number, $d$ as the number of sides on our die, and $n$ as the number of dice thrown. For a single dice, we can define our probability of reaching the target number as $\frac{d-t+1}{d}$, which leads to our probability of *not* reaching the target number as $\frac{t-1}{d}$. We can then get out our trusty equation for finding the probability of $x$ successes from a binomial distribution:

$$P(X=x)=\binom{n}{x}\left (\frac{d-t+1}{d}\right )^x\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n-x}$$

Of course, we can simplify this down even further - since we only want the probability of *any* success at all, we can simply calculate the probability of *no* successes, and subtract that from one. since $\binom{n}{0} = 1$ for all n, and $\left (\frac{d-t+1}{d}\right )^0=1$, we can streamline our equation to:

$$P(X>0)=1-\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n}$$

This, will give you the probability of any of $n$ dice hitting your target number. At this point, we just need to account for the probability of any dice hitting "1" (I *assume* that it's not just the first dice we need to worry about hitting a 1 on). We can repeat the same process above to find *that* equation, and subtract that from the first:

\begin{align*}
P(X>0)&=1-\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n}-\left (1- \left (\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n}\right )\\
&=-\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n}+\left (\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n}\\
&=\left (\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n}-\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n}
\end{align*}

To find how much the probability changes if we increase $n$ by one, we just need to subtract one from the other. In fact, let's make this a bit more general, and define $m$ as our change in number of dice:
\begin{align*}
\delta(n,m) &= \left (\left (\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n+m}-\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n+m}\right )-\left (\left (\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n}-\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n}\right )\\
&=\left (\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n+m}-\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n+m}-\left (\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n}+\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n}\\
&=\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n}-\left (\frac{t-1}{d}\right)^{n+m}+\left (\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n+m}-\left (\frac{d-1}{d}\right)^{n}\\
\end{align*}

So, that gives us a neat and simple formula for just the d20s, the next question is about adding an additional $d_2$-sided die to the result for each throw. Let's think it through - adding an additional die cannot *substract* from the probability of success we have here - an extra die can only *add* to the probability of success, and it's doing this by effectively *reducing* our target number by no less than 1 and no more than $d_2$, and for each of those possibilities, we multiply it by the probability of getting that result, like so:

\begin{align*}P(X=x)=& \sum_{k=1}^{d_2}\left ( \left ( \frac{d_1-t+k+1}{d_1} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{d_2} \right )  \right )^1\left ( \left ( \frac{t-k-1}{d_1} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{d_2} \right )\right )^0\\
=&\sum_{k=1}^{d_2} \left ( \frac{d_1-t+k+1}{d_1d_2} \right )^1 \left ( \frac{t-k-1}{d_1d_2} \right )^0
\end{align*}

We can then expand this to multiple dice as:

$$P(X=x)=\sum_{k=1}^{d_2}\binom{n}{x} \left ( \frac{d_1-t+k+1}{d_1d_2} \right )^x \left ( \frac{t-k-1}{d_1d_2} \right )^{n-x}$$

Again, we only care about whether *any* dice exceeds the target, so we can once again reduce this down to:

$$P(X>0)= 1-\sum_{k=1}^{d_2}\left ( \frac{t-k-1}{d_1d_2} \right )^n$$

Then account for 1s always failing:

$$P(X>0)= \left (\frac{d_1-1}{d_1}  \right )^n-\sum_{k=1}^{d_2}\left ( \frac{t-k-1}{d_1d_2} \right )^n$$

And then rebuild the delta equation to get the probability delta:

\begin{align*} \delta(n,m) =& \left (\left (\frac{d_1-1}{d_1}  \right )^{n+m}-\sum_{k=1}^{d_2}\left ( \frac{t-k-1}{d_1d_2} \right )^{n+m}  \right )-\left (\left (\frac{d_1-1}{d_1}  \right )^{n}-\sum_{k=1}^{d_2}\left ( \frac{t-k-1}{d_1d_2} \right )^{n}  \right )\\
=& \left (\frac{d_1-1}{d_1}  \right )^{n+m}-\left (\frac{d_1-1}{d_1}  \right )^{n} +\sum_{k=1}^{d_2}\left ( \frac{t-k-1}{d_1d_2} \right )^{n} -\left ( \frac{t-k-1}{d_1d_2} \right )^{n+m} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

If the target is $t$ and we have $n$ dice with sides $s_1, s_2, s_3, ... s_n$ (note the indices are not the number of sides).

We then calculate in how many ways we can get $t$. Let's say it's $m$.

The probability of hitting the target $t = \frac{m}{s_1 \times s_2 \times ... \times s_n}$

Calculating $m$ is an issue ... but a clever answer I saw on a related question is this: With $n$ dice with sides $s_1, s_2, ..., s_n$, the coefficients of the following will give you the number of ways a specific target can be hit:

$(x + x^2 + ... + x^{s_1})(x + x^2 + ... + x^{s_2}) ... (x + x^2 + ... + x^{s_n})$

So for $1$ three-sided die and $1$ two-sided die, $(x + x^2)(x + x^2 + x^3) = x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 = x^2 + 2x^3 + 2x^4 + x^5$

In how many ways can you get a 3? Look at the coefficient of $x^3$. It's $2$, viz $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$